# Thread stop in while True loop

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, global-variables

I'm working on Threads on Python 3. Motive is to run a loop while keyboard interrupt.

Thread.run() => It start my loop but does not end with keyboard interrupt.
Thread.start() => iterate loop only once and then stop.

```
import threading as td
global run
run = True
def printThread():
    global run
    while run:
        print('Hello world! run = ', run)    

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    thread1 = td.Thread(target=printThread, name='t1')
    thread1.start()
    input()
    print(run)
    run = False
    thread1.join()    
    print('got it')
    input()
```

I except to run my code as worked in c++ thread.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
static bool run = true;
void dowork()
{
  while(run)
  std::cout << "hello";
}

int main()
{
    std::thread worker(dowork);
    std::cin.get();
    run = false;
    worker.join();
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine. Are you pressing enter?

Comment: Yes sir, I'm pressing enter. In my PC after this "Hello world! run = " loop is not continuously printing  "Hello world! run = True".

Comment: In both cases, you have a race condition accessing the `run` variable. Probably not a big deal because of the GIL.

Comment: Thank You all. The problem was i was executing it on IDLE when I run it on cmd it works fine. Thank you very much once again